# Append to struct slice in golang

Tags: go

I tried hard to find example as mine, but although bunch of questions are very similar, I wasnt able to understand what I am doing wrong.

I am very new to golang, and I am trying to implement game of life.

here is part of my code

```
// Species struct
type Species struct {
    xPos            int32
    yPos            int32
    isAlive         bool
    willChangeState bool
    rect            sdl.Rect
    neighbours      []Species
}

type Ecosystem struct {
    community []Species
}

func (ecos *Ecosystem) addSpecies(sp Species) {
    ecos.community = append(ecos.community, sp)
}

func (s *Species) addNeigbour(neigbour Species) {
    s.neighbours = append(s.neighbours, neigbour)
}
```

I want to distribute neighbours as in this function

```
func (ecos *Ecosystem) distributeNeighbours() {
    for _, species := range ecos.community {
        for _, potentionalNeighbour := range ecos.community {
            if math.Abs(float64(species.xPos-potentionalNeighbour.xPos)) <= speciesSize && math.Abs(float64(species.yPos-potentionalNeighbour.yPos)) <= speciesSize {
                if species.xPos == potentionalNeighbour.xPos && species.yPos == potentionalNeighbour.yPos {
                    continue
                }
                species.addNeigbour(potentionalNeighbour)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(len(species.neighbours)) // works here
    }
    for _, s := range ecos.community {
        fmt.Println(len(s.neighbours)) //prints 0
    }
}
```

So I guess I have to manage it with pointers - some issue like species in first loop is copy of that species in community, so original species does not gain any neigbours. But I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Change the slice fields to `[]*Species`.

Comment: Or update the element in ecos.community after appending.

Comment: I would just use the index when looping on community (for i := range ecos.community). To don’t repeat the 'i', do: “species := &ecos.community[i]” on the 1st line in the loop, so the rest of your loop stay the same, but will modify community.

Answer (score 1):

Try slice of pointer, like this:

```
// Species struct
type Species struct {
    xPos            int32
    yPos            int32
    isAlive         bool
    willChangeState bool
    rect            sdl.Rect
    neighbours      []*Species
}

type Ecosystem struct {
    community []*Species
}
```